# Suppose $\lim x_{n} = x$, and $x\neq0$, show that there is an $N \in \mathbb N$ so that if $n\geq N$ then $|x_{n}|\geq \frac{|x|}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

If {$x_{n}$} is a sequence of real numbers for which $\lim x_{n} = x$, and if $x\neq0$, then prove that there is an $N \in \mathbb N$ so that if $n\geq N$ then $|x_{n}|\geq \frac{|x|}{2}$. Hint: Make use of the positive number $\epsilon =\frac{|x|}{2}$. You may need to use the triangle inequality for a difference.

So far, I have: Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Since $\lim x_{n} = x$, applying the definition of a limit with $\epsilon = \frac{|x|}{2}$, we have an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_{n}-x|< \frac{|x|}{2}$ for any $n \geq N$.

So I know that as long as I can prove that $|x_{n}|> \frac{|x|}{2}$ then it sufficient. However. I am not sure where to use the given hint of the triangle inequality. Any help is appreciated. Also please explain each step after what I have.

Comment: I have seen the following: If x > 0, $|x_{n}-x|< \frac{|x|}{2}$ implies $a_{n}> x - |x/2| = |x|/2 >0 $ and if x < 0, $|x_{n}-x|< \frac{|x|}{2}$ implies  $a_{n} < x + |x/2| = - |x|+|x|/2 = -|x|/2$. In both cases $|x_{n}|> \frac{|x|}{2}$. But I am not sure how this happens. If anyone can explain in detail.

Comment: You can use that $|x_n - x| \geq ||x_n| - |x||$, in particular, $|x| - |x_n| \leq |x_n - x|$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition of limit, we have

$|x_n - x| < \epsilon$ for $n \ge N$

But $|x| - |x_n| \le ||x| - |x_n|| \le |x_n - x|$ by reverse triangle inequality

Putting the two together,

$|x_n| > |x| - \epsilon$

now set epsilon as mentioned above since this holds for all positive epsilon